# How Can I copy data in the same table in sql except the primary key?

Tags: sql

I have a table `Flights` with columns `f_no`, `origincity`, `destionationcity`, `smallow`, etc

I want to copy every column except the `f_no`.

`f_no` is not auto incremented. i.e  I have myself assigned unique values to them for eg. 10101, 79102, 24456 etc.

Answer (score 0):

First You want to Export table then make it csv file then open in excel,

remove f_no column assign value whatever then import table in database

Answer (score 0):

Export table from Database then open in excel file.

Answer (score 0):

first create temporary table first move data to temporary table

```
  INSERT INTO FlightsTemp (origincity,destionationcity, smallow,...)
  SELECT (origincity,destionationcity, smallow,...) FROM Flights;
```

then delete all the records from Flights table, then alter Flights table and make f_no as auto-incremented

and again insert data back to Flights table

```
INSERT INTO Flights (origincity,destionationcity, smallow,...)
SELECT (origincity,destionationcity, smallow,...) FROM FlightsTemp;
```